# Adding .style and class to a array element [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a colorful logo to be exact to fade in and out a random color on hover for each letter in the logo. When I console.log(word) without other parameters I get array My Portfolio, but it seems I can't add styles or add classes to elements in array. I realize that it makes sense why it doesn't work but how to approach this so I get the rainbow effect.

```
let logo = document.querySelector("#rainbow");

    function transition() {
  let words = logo.textContent.split("");
  words.forEach((word) => {
    word.style.color = getRandomColor();
    word.classList.toggle("fade");
  })
}
logo.addEventListener("mouseover", transition());

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  var color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="/" id="rainbow" class="navbar-brand">My Portfolio</a>
```

Thanks!

BTW please without Jquery.

Comment: You need to make every character into an element (span, probably) and set styles for those. Characters in an array aren’t DOM elements so they can’t be styled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change style of a single character. In your `words.foreach`, you are getting a character in the `word` variable. You have to create a different element for each character to change it's color. The change here will be that in the foreach, you will create different elements for each letter and set their style accordingly then add them as a child of the `anchor`.

```js
let logo = document.querySelector("#rainbow");

function transition() {
  let words = logo.textContent.split("");
  logo.innerHTML = ""; // Remove previous word
  words.forEach((word) => {
    var current = document.createElement("span"); // Create element
    current.style.color = getRandomColor();
    current.innerHTML = word
    current.classList.toggle("fade"); // CSS class for fade in/out
    logo.appendChild(current); // Add as child of anchor
  })
}
logo.addEventListener("mouseover", transition());

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  var color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" id="rainbow" class="navbar-brand">My Portfolio</a>
```

Comment: This work partially for now:https://prnt.sc/taynt9 Also question it fades in automatically why is event triggered without hovering on a logo?

Comment: Did you do this? `logo.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm blind. Added it problem solved. The only problem I have now it is triggering immediately

Comment: I think that would be because in `logo.addEventListener("mouseover", transition());`, you use function name and not the parantheses. So, it would be `logo.addEventListener("mouseover", transition);`

Comment: A couple more things, if you don't want the changing color everytime the mouse is moved while hovering, you should use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`. Then if you want to remove the rainbow elements from the logo after the mouse leaves, you should add another `mouseleave` listener and call a `reset` function which will have a single line, `logo.innerHTML = "My Portfolio"`. That should reset it.

Comment: The moment I started the script  I saw that mouseover won't work :) Changed it to mouseover added reset function everything works great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make each letter in a different color, you need to wrap each inside a span element and add the color style to that element each time, you can see that in online code highlighters.

I made it dynamic, so you can call the ranbowit function on any html element to make its text in ranbow style.

```js
const randNum = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max),
  getRandomColor = _=> `rgb(${randNum(256)},${randNum(256)},${randNum(256)})`;
  rainbowIt = element => element.innerHTML = element.innerText.split("").map(letter =>
    `<span style="color: ${getRandomColor()}">${letter}</span>`).join("");

document.querySelectorAll("body *").forEach(element => rainbowIt(element));
```

```html
<h1>My Portfolio</h1>
<h2>My Portfolio</h2>
<h3>My Portfolio</h3>
<h4>My Portfolio</h4>
<h5>My Portfolio</h5>
<h6>My Portfolio</h6>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer luctus diam ut cursus pretium. Quisque a pharetra augue. Duis sagittis diam ut augue tristique, sit amet sagittis felis blandit. Ut ornare magna ac urna pulvinar, nec bibendum leo pellentesque. Suspendisse ullamcorper viverra facilisis. Aenean ornare risus at dolor laoreet, eget pretium ante ultrices. Fusce fringilla felis vel sapien dignissim, at finibus dolor commodo. Morbi nec gravida tortor. Nunc euismod pulvinar elementum. Fusce at massa volutpat, maximus mauris vel, aliquet nisl. Cras nec nisl nec purus tristique semper. Aenean imperdiet mi diam, at vehicula orci iaculis ut. Nullam bibendum, tellus nec egestas tristique, nibh leo feugiat lectus, eget posuere justo tellus et sem. Vivamus suscipit dignissim nunc, in eleifend metus sollicitudin at. In consectetur tincidunt purus. Duis molestie consequat lacus, sed commodo metus porta in.</p>
```

**Note:**
If you are not familiar with ES6 features, here is the same in old syntax and documented as well:

```
// get a random number 0-255 both included, just to get random rgb values
function randNum(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
// get a random rgb style text for example `rgb(239, 143, 12)`
function getRandomColor() {
  return "rgb(" + randNum(256) + "," + randNum(256) + "," + randNum(256) + ")";
}
/* get all the letters from the element and make an array, loop over it and wrap
each letter in a span element with a random color style, then convert it to text 
and add it to the element*/
function rainbowIt(element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerText.split("").map(function(letter) {
    return '<span style="color: ' + getRandomColor() + '">' + letter + '</span>';
  }).join("");
}
// loop over all the children of body just for demonstration
document.querySelectorAll("body *").forEach(function(element) {
  rainbowIt(element);
});
```

Comment: I belive this would work for me. From reading it I understand it, its just too advanced for me now. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: How can I simplify it?! you can use the second piece of code, or maybe you can ask me whatever you want, it's ok we're here to help